# When i upload my asp.net and database files to the server and try to open the website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008-r2

it works on my laptop but when i upload it on the server does not work and say this :

```
  The network path was not found
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

 Source Error:


 Line 58:             using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select word_text from words where word_id = 1", con))
Line 59:             {
 Line 60:                 con.Open(); "That show in red"
 Line 61:                 SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
 Line 62:                 if (dr.Read())
```

That is my connection string from server:

```
      Connection string:    workstation id=textdatabase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=Naeemh_SQLLogin_1;pwd=t7xtp3wlad;data source=textdatabase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=textdatabase
```

That the connection where was in my laptop:

`Connection string:Data Source=Q-PC;Initial Catalog=Text;Integrated` `Security=True`

Comment: It might be that database connection is not correct.

Comment: It is correct i am sure.

Comment: It write     con.Open();   in red when i open from server

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the database it's telling you what the error is .. do you have hard coded paths in your `.aspx page or code behind` you need to show the code that's relevant how do you know that this is the line where it's causing the error it could be code that's above prior to hitting this line.. edit the question and show all relevant code..also add some logging so you know exactly where it's throwing the error.. where is the Trace Log..? then again show us the actual connection string because Paths on your local are never the same on the remote server..

Answer (score 0):

I forget to change my

```
connection string in the ASP.NET files
```